# Android Live Wallpaper Tap Event

Tags: android, event-handling, live-wallpaper

When you want to handle a click in your life wallpaper you should use onCommand and wait for the action WallpaperManager.COMMAND_TAP. This is described e.g. in the discussion thread: [Android Live Wallpaper Touch Event Hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298458/android-live-wallpaper-touch-event-hierarchy).

This works fine on my phone, but when i deploy the wallpaper to a tablet (in my case the motorola xoom with android 3.1) COMMAND_TAP is also triggered, when an icon on the home-screen is pressed.

I added a workaround by storing the visible state and delaying the onCommand handling by 1000ms, but I would like a real solution for this problem.

Comment: I'm seeing this on the Samsung Galaxy S II also, but not on most other phones. It also happens when a widget is pressed. Can you give details of your workaround?

Comment: How is this still a problem on Android 8.0?! Nexus 5x stock factory image.

Comment: I reported it on the Android issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68467342

Answer (score 0):

We're having the same issues with Samsung phones, only verified on the Droid Charge SCH-I510 and S2. The S3 does not exhibit the behavior.

Here is the workaround, that Gizmomogwai mentioned in code.

```
public Bundle onCommand(String action, int x, int y, int z, Bundle extras, boolean resultRequested) {
  if (WallpaperManager.COMMAND_TAP.equals(action)) {
    final CustomWallpaperEngine that = this;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        if(that.isVisible()) {
          // valid tap command
          // DO STUFF
        } else {
          // Invalid tap command, throw away
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```