# Opening app or URL in Live Wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have an app which basically loads a URL. The page on this URL has a few buttons to control few things.
Now, I want to make a Live Wallpaper app which will set my app as the live wallpaper. Is it possible to do so?
If it is not possible, then can I open the required URL when I try to set Live Wallpaper?

So, ultimately, I want to set my app as the Live Wallpaper. This will need me to open the URL and set the opened page as the live wallpaper.

Thank.
Sagar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can respond to touch events in the live wallpaper (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298458/android-live-wallpaper-touch-event-hierarchy) and so you could recreate your app UI in the wallpaper, and respond to the touch events on the buttons manually (by comparing the location of the tap with the boundaries of the button images and responding if a button is "pressed").

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Apart from the touch events, can u tell me how to open the URL n set the opened page as live wallpaper ( as I mentioned in the edited question)? (As it's a wallpaper, I suspect, we cant open a webview as the service wont use main.xml)
Also can u throw some light on 'recreating app UI in the wallpaper'?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but i'm afraid it's only theoretically possible, not practically. Previous user was right, you can respond to touch events in a live wallpaper and you can connect to the internet - yes. 
But please let me expand this:

> recreate your app UI in the wallpaper

- you don't get any windows or views in your live wallpaper app;
- you don't get any buttons or responders in your live wallpaper app;

Only preference activity is an activity but it is really an optional view to visit for user.

All you have is a surface which you can draw on using either OpenGL or Canvas. It would take you to re-implement browser in you live wallpaper using only what Canvas gives you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for throwing more light and giving more details about implementation.
And I am sorry for replying after such a long time as I was put on a different project and was completely away from Android development.